# Change entry in a CSV file with PHP

Tags: php, csv

I have a CSV file with three columns:
Mary,150203_15:29:12,150203_16:10:12
John,150203_15:29:17,pending
Peter,150203_15:29:35,150203_15:49:35
Olga,150203_15:30:43,pending
...
..
.
Mary,150204_15:42:14,pending
Peter,150204_20:42:14,pending

Because there are many entries on that file all I want to do is 
find the latest entry according to the Username and change the last value (from pending to date()). 
In the example above lets say I want to change the latest Mary entry in the 3rd column from pending to date. Then replace the updated CSV file with the current one.

Any ideas on how to approach that?

Thank you

Comment: *My 2 cents* - So much easier working with a DB instead.

Comment: You'll need to parse the entire file and then sort it otherwise you cant really find the latest for a given user. You should really use a DB for this... Or baring that then something that can hold structure like XML, JSON, or YAML. You'd still need to load the entire file but you can it least get all the entries for a username easily. And finding the latest entry just becomes using a filtering loop on that subset of data for a specific user.

Comment: @manny Does the record you want to work on always end in "pending" and is the combination of User Name and "pending" always unique?

Comment: Normally there will be a unique Username set to pending. all other entries with the same Username will have the date() value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work with the file as one huge string and do a string replacement.

```
$data = file_get_contents('your_file.csv');
$data = str_replace('Joe,150203_16:21:43,pending','Joe,15203_16:21:43,15204_15:23:43',$data);
file_put_contents('your_file.csv', $data);
```

The comments below raise a concern of finding out what the latest date is for a name. That is also rather simple to do. Assuming you've loaded $data in, as above...

```
$matches = array(); // Just to point out that this is an array
preg_match_all("/Joe,(.*),/", $data, $matches);
```

Now, $matches[1] contains all the dates for Joe. Did you ONLY want the ones that are pending? No problem...

```
preg_match_all("/Joe,(.*),pending/", $data, $matches);
```

Now, $matches[1] only contains the pending dates. Which is the most recent?

```
rsort($mathes[1]);
```

Now, $matches[1][0] is the most recent date. So, you can do:

```
$data = str_replace('Joe,'.$matches[1][0].',pending','Joe,'.$matches[1][0].',15204_15:23:43',$data);
```

Is this the absolute most efficient way to do this? No. Is it impossibly hard? No. You *should* look into using a proper database, but it is *possible* to use csv files.

Comment: 'cept you don't know how many times "Joe" appears in the file and you don't know in advance what the first time string is. As Fred said above, a great time to explore a DB.

Comment: Correct. However, there are things like preg_match to get all the instances of Joe and all the dates. Instead of assuming that this is absolutely hopeless, think. The tools are available. It is harder than using a database, but he already chose to use csv instead of a database.

Comment: Can you improve your answer by adding the preg_match parts? I'm not assuming its hopeless, I'm suggesting it would be a great time to brush up on some DB skills.

Comment: I used the simplest regex possible. It will fail if a person has a comma in her or her name. It is possible to match specifically ,(\d{6}_\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}), - but I don't want this to derail into a discussion of why you shouldn't use regular expressions on non-regular languages (ie: free-text).

Answer (score 0):

If moving the data to a DB is not a solution in your case, you could do the following:

1. Read the CSV file into PHP via fgetcsv(), line by line, into an
   array
2. Sort the array based on your criteria and get the latest entry
3. Update the entry
4. Write the entries back into the file via fputcsv()

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a much simpler solution to this. Was the simplest one I could come up with.

```
$line = $_SESSION[username].",".$_SESSION[LOGIN_TIME].",".'pending'."\r\n"; 
$newline = $_SESSION[username].","$_SESSION[LOGIN_TIME].",".date("ymd_H:i:s"). "\r\n";
$data = file_get_contents('login.log');
$data = str_replace($line,$newline,$data);
file_put_contents('login.log', $data);
```

So there is no need for scanning for the latest entry. I just store the previous entry values and replace them with the new ones.

Thank you  kainaw and BigScar

Comment: Now that you have that much done, it is time to look at file locking. Without file locking, you may have a race condition that causes errors in your data file.